# AWS AutoScale instance is stuck at "Pending:Proceed" state

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

From what I understand when a new autoscaling instance is created it first goes into Pending:Wait state, and then after receiving a life cycle event it goes into Pending:Proceed state.

1. What is the purpose of the Pending:Proceed state? (I figured it's just a brief temporary state between the complete-lifecycle-action and the instance actually being added)
2. How does an instance go from Pending:Proceed to InService state? Do I need to take any actions?

Answer (score 1):

Pending: Proceed is a state between your complete-lifecycle action and the addition of the instance under ELB, followed by a healthcheck/heartbeat. Pending: Proceed usually means that your instance will be added to the Auto scaling group under an ELB and healthchecks start on the instance.

If your instance is stuck in "pending: proceed", i would check the following

1. did the complete-life-cycle go through fine?
2. Is the ELB actually running fine?

Comment: Thanks! Well if I'm in 'pending:proceed' wouldn't it mean that  complete-life-cycle went through?